# SQL Server 2012 - Developer Edition Questions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I could not find much information about the Developer Edition of SQL Server 2012 on Microsoft's website, so I figured I would just ask a few simple questions here.

1. Is there a place to purchase a digital copy of the software?
2. I just wanted to make sure that I can use SSIS with the Developer Edition as that is the main reason I want it (it won't let me craete SSIS packages in the Express Edition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Developer Edition is functionally *identical* to the **Enterprise** edition (it just doesn't have a license to use it legally in a production environment).

See the [SQL Server web site for the Enterprise edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/enterprise.aspx) for the full feature list.

So yes, most definitely, it has SSIS and everything in the box.

And I believe it should be available for purchase at large online software vendors, too - depends on your location, I guess. E.g. at [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007RFXQAM), if you're in the US.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I live in Washington state. I can order it on Amazon, but was hoping to just be able to download it, or purchase a key.